# How can I disable ASLR on FreeBSD?

Tags: c++, c, security, freebsd

I'm currently taking a computer security class and would like to try to port some of the class example exploits to my FreeBSD machine.  For linux, I was able to disable `ASLR` by using

```
"echo 0 > /proc/sys/kernel/randomize_va_space".  Compiling with "-fno-stack-protector -z execstack"
```

flags on `gcc` disables `NX` and `canaries`, and I assume that will be the same for FreeBSD.  Does FreeBSD have similar functionality to disable ASLR though?
Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no address space randomization feature on FreeBSD.

Comment: That's slightly disconcerting, but it does simplify things for this task.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Running-config:

```
sysctl kern.elf64.aslr.enable=0
sysctl kern.elf32.aslr.enable=0
```

To persist changes:

```
vi /boot/loader.conf
kern.elf64.aslr.enable=0
kern.elf32.aslr.enable=0
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are an a explanation about [ASLR on FreeBSD](http://www.haibane.org/node/11)